# How to sum identical consecutiveentries inside a list of integers into a new list?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of `[4,8,4,4,2,2,2,16]` and I want to make `[4,8,8,6,16]` out of it.

How do I do it? I've tried for and while loops, but can't get it to work.

Comment: If someone can find a decent duplicate, I can mark it

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> lst = [4,8,4,4,2,2,2,16] 
>>> [sum(g) for _, g in groupby(lst)]
[4, 8, 8, 6, 16]
```